# How can I re-write this strcpy() function using pointers only?

Tags: c

this is strcpy code

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char* src)
#endif
{
    char *ret = dest;
    while (*dest++ = *src++)
        ;
    return ret;
}
```

I tried to implement it using swap method and pointers only

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
char *ret = dest;
dest = src;
src = ret;
return ret
}
```

but the swap method didn't work,can any one tell me if it's proper to use swap method to perform strcpy() function? if not, how can I write this code using ponters notation only?

Comment: why would you change `src = ret`? the source should not be changed

Comment: Why would you think swapping pointers would perform a copy operation?

Comment: If `strcpy(x, y);` meant the same thing as `x = y;`, people would just write that.

Comment: In function declaration of strcpy if you look close you can see that src is `const char*` its declared like that because value of address pointed by src shouldn't be changed inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

> can any one tell me if it's proper to use swap method to perform
>   strcpy() function?

No, it's not proper, because that it not was `strcpy()` does.  I think you'd better read the [strcpy() man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) again -- there's a reason it is named `strcpy()` (which is an abbreviation of "string copy") and not `swap_char_pointers()`.

> if not, how can I write this code using ponters notation only?

The first `strcpy()` implementation that you posted uses pointer notation only, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

strcpy should make you dest contain the src content. If you change the pointer itself, you won't get a copy.
You can try something like :

```
int x = 0;
while (src[x] != '\0'){
dest[x] = src[x];
x++;
}
dest[x] = '\0';
```

You don't have to touch the src. Keep in mind that dest is only the adress of your string, you can't change it if you want to make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

`dest` and `scr` are local variables inside the function. Changes you make to them are not reflected outside.

Also, strings in C are character arrays you cannot change the starting address of an array its kind of like constant.